# NSMutableArray can not release objects after invoke removeAllObjects

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm a new guy for developing ios app.

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* dataBufferArray;
```

Following code run in a callback function.which invoked frequently.

```
[analyzer.dataBufferArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:thisFrame]];
[analyzer.dataBufferArray removeAllObjects];
```

**Code run in ARC**.
I found the memory always growing! Finally IOS exit my application cause by huge memory consume.

My question is: why removeAllObjects can not release the memory? 
How to resolve it?

post more code

```
static int analyze(SAMPLE *inputBuffer,
        unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
        AudioSignalAnalyzer *analyzer) {

    SAMPLE *pSample = inputBuffer;

    for (long i = 0; i  SAMPLE_RATE){
        NSArray* unitSampleArray = [analyzer.dataBufferArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, SAMPLE_RATE  - 1)];
        [analyzer.dataBufferArray removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, SAMPLE_RATE  - 1)];

        //use thread to process
       NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]initWithTarget:analyzer
                                                                               selector:@selector(decodeSound:)
                                                                                 object:unitSampleArray];
        [analyzer.queue addOperation: operation];
    }
        // for protect
    if (analyzer.dataBufferArray.count > SAMPLE_RATE * 12){
        NSLog(@"sample in data buffer so big, need clear");
        [analyzer.dataBufferArray removeAllObjects];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, analyze function is callback by AudioQueueNewInput.
I used NSMutableArray add object NSNumber, and I always 'removeObjectsInRange:' them. I use instruments to check the memory, it always growing!

Comment: Your problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: This code looks ok, problem lies somewhere else. Share some more detail what are you trying to do.

Comment: I test change the code: [analyzer.dataBufferArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:thisFrame]];  to [analyzer.dataBufferArray addObject:@"test"];  the memory not growing.... Does 'NSNumber' object need release manual after removing from NSMutableArray?

Comment: Have you run your code using instruments with the leak tool?  Presumably between adding the number to the array and removing it from the array you perform some other processing?  And presumably when you added @"test" you had to bypass this other processing because the array doesn't contain a number?  This other code would seem to contain the problem

Comment: yes, I using instruments tool knowing the memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ARC based project there is no need to release memory, it will automatically managed. Your problem is somewhere else please post some more code.

Comment: hi, I added code, please help to check. if you need more information, please talk.